# Disable location.href for specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have build a script that makes the rows of my DataTable clickable.

When the I click on a row, the browser navigates me to the location: ./test.php?id=

The problem now is that I have a column that has a checkbox in it. The script also navigates me to the location when I clock on the checkbox.

I want to make the second column (target 1) not 'clickable'. When I click on the second column the script should not navigate me to the location: ./test.php?id=

Does someone know how I can realize that?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('grid1').DataTable({
   "bprocessing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "response1.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "error": function(){
                $("#grid_processing").css("display","none");
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [ 
            { "targets": 0, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' '+data+' '} },
            { "targets": 1, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<div class="checkbox c-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="sel1"/><span class="fa fa-check"></span></label></div>'} },
            { "targets": 2, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' '+data+' '} },
            { "targets": 3, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' '+data+' '} },
            { "targets": 4, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' '+data+' '} },
            { "targets": 5, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' '} }
        ]                                    
  });   
 });
</script>
```

Here is the script that creates the clickable row:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#grid1').DataTable();    
    $('#grid1').on( "click", "td", function (e) {
      var rowIdx = table.row( this ).index();
      var sData = table.cells({ row: rowIdx, column: 5 }).data()[0];
      if (sData && sData.length) {
        location.href = './test.php?id=' + sData;
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: You're actually making each cell clickable with your script (the target is `td`, not `tr`), so just check what column it's in, and if it's in the column you don't want clickable, return false instead of setting `location.href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try changing your on click selector to something like

```
$('#grid1').on( "click", "td:not(:nth-child(2))", function (e) {
      var rowIdx = table.row( this ).index();
      var sData = table.cells({ row: rowIdx, column: 5 }).data()[0];
      if (sData && sData.length) {
        location.href = './test.php?id=' + sData;
      }
    });
```